# Only select ID's which have not a fully numeric value

Tags: sql

I want to select only ID's in a certain column which dont have numeric values only.
For example:

I want to select:

```
a12345
```

But not:

```
123456
```

It is a nvarchar(15) field.

Is this even possible in SQL?

Greets

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The answer will probably be product specific.)

Answer (score 1):

Try 'isnumeric' (assuming MSSQL);

```
select * from MyTable where isnumeric(MyField)=0
```

Answer (score 0):

For your specific problem of the first character, you can do:

```
where substr(col, 1, 1) not between '0' and '9'
```

This should work in almost any database (although `substr()` might be spelled `substring()`).

There are better solutions, but they are specific to a given database.

Answer (score 0):

If SQL Server 2012+, I would use `try_convert()` which returns NULL for any conversion errors

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] nvarchar(15))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('a12345')
,('12345')
,('123-45')
,('12345z')

Select * from @YourTable
 where try_convert(int,ID) is null
```

**Returns**

```
ID
a12345
123-45
12345z
```